# ArcGIS definition query

Tags: sql, arcgis

I am working with agriculture and looking at two farms.

Each one has the same `Farm Number (FSN)` so I am trying to show particular tracts of land from those `FSN`s and particular `Common Land Units (CLUs)`.

Is there a way to write a query to basically tell the system, `"I want to see clus 1 and 2 from tract 443 and clus 1 and 4 from tract 442 both from farm 551?`

I have been creating new layers for each tract, but I know there has to be a more elegant way to do this.

This is what I have for getting one tract:

```
state_code = '22' AND county_code = '053' AND farm_number = '516' AND tract_number = '228' AND clu_number IN ('17', '21')`
```

What would I need to do to get another `tract` and its `clus` from the same farm in this query?

I know that in ArcGIS there is a query builder which uses SQL to define the data being used for a particular map layer. In the query builder the select statement is written and you are providing the information after "where:".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received an answer outside this forum but it may prove useful for others.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/208363/81404